# Prometheus - Monitoring number of files - avg_over_time is giving a huge number

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I've just a service that creates 2 files each 30 seconds on a specific directory using python, and I'm using Prometheus/Grafana to evaluate the number of files being uploaded over time, with the metric that I've created on Prometheus named **txt_files_data__total**. Sometimes I just upload more files to my directory manually so I can see the variance on my chart.

My main goal is to calculate two expressions using Grafana:

- The number of files being generated by each minute
- Validate if the number of files being generated each minute is very different by the average number of files generated each minute on the last 24h.

For the first expression, I am able to calculate using:

```
increase(txt_files_data__total{instance="localhost:9999",job="python"}[1m])
```

But my second expression is giving abnormal numbers (my calculation is that I should have a value like 4.777 but I am getting 30/40 number of files):

```
avg_over_time(txt_files_data__total{instance="localhost:9999",job="python"}[24h:1m])
```

I just export the Grafana data as a table:

[image]

And you can see the grafana chart:
[image]

Am I making any mistake calculating those metrics?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following query must return the average number of files being generated per minute over the last 24 hours:

```
avg_over_time(
  increase(txt_files_data__total{instance="localhost:9999",job="python"}[1m])[20s:24h]
)
```

This query uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).